# SendGrid is not sending an email

Tags: c#, razor, sendgrid

I have been following this tutorial: http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/security/create-an-aspnet-mvc-5-web-app-with-email-confirmation-and-password-reset . I have gone through it three times now and checked through several Stackoverflow posts, but I still don't know what I am missing. Through debugging Visual Studio shows that myMessage has all that it needs (email address to deliver to, message subject, message body, who it is coming from, etc), but I am not actually receiving an email for confirmation when I test it. This is the code I currently have:

IdentityConfig.cs

```
public class EmailService : IIdentityMessageService
{
    public async Task SendAsync(IdentityMessage message)
    {
        // Plug in your email service here to send an email.
        // line below was commented out and replaced upon tutorial request
        //return Task.FromResult(0);
        await configSendGridasync(message);
    }
    // Use NuGet to install SendGrid (Basic C# client lib) 
    private async Task configSendGridasync(IdentityMessage message)
    {
        var myMessage = new SendGridMessage();
        myMessage.AddTo(message.Destination);
        myMessage.From = new System.Net.Mail.MailAddress(
                            "myActualEmail@email.com", "Robert");
        myMessage.Subject = message.Subject;
        myMessage.Text = message.Body;
        myMessage.Html = message.Body;

        var credentials = new NetworkCredential(
                   ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["mailAccount"],
                   ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["mailPassword"]
                   );

        // Create a Web transport for sending email.
        var transportWeb = new Web(credentials);

        // Send the email.
        if (transportWeb != null)
        {
            await transportWeb.DeliverAsync(myMessage);
        }
        else
        {
            Trace.TraceError("Failed to create Web transport.");
            await Task.FromResult(0);
        }
    }
}
```

AccountController:

```
[HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Register(RegisterViewModel model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var user = new ApplicationUser { UserName = model.UserName, Email = model.Email };
            var result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);
            if (result.Succeeded)
            {
                // commented below code and RedirectToAction out so it didn't auto log you in.
                //await SignInManager.SignInAsync(user, isPersistent:false, rememberBrowser:false);

                //For more information on how to enable account confirmation and password reset please visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=320771
                //Send an email with this link
                string code = await UserManager.GenerateEmailConfirmationTokenAsync(user.Id);
                var callbackUrl = Url.Action("ConfirmEmail", "Account", new { userId = user.Id, code = code }, protocol: Request.Url.Scheme);
                await UserManager.SendEmailAsync(user.Id, "Confirm your account", "Please confirm your account by clicking <a href=\"" + callbackUrl + "\">here</a>");

                ViewBag.Message = "Check your email and confirm your account, you must be confirmed before you can log in.";

                return View("Info");

                //return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
            }
            AddErrors(result);
        }

        // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
        return View(model);
    }
```

Web.config:

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="webpages:Version" value="3.0.0.0" />

    <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />

    <add key="mailAccount" value="azure_d8aedad6a68a0dc1dc8axxxxxxxxxxxx@azure.com" /> <!--the mailAccount that SendGrid gave me through Azure marketplace to use-->
    <add key="mailPassword" value="xxxxxx" /> <!--password taken out, but I used the one from SendGrid-->
</appSettings>
```

The code builds and runs with no errors, but I never get the actual email when I test it (I have used two separate gmail accounts and a yahoo account). Any advice/help would be appreciated!

Comment: I have had issues with sendgrid sending from my local dev machine, but once I have deployed it to a server / host it worked as expected. (for what its worth)

Comment: Not 100% sure what is available to you on the SendGrid side, but it looks like there is a dashboard of some sort. Any indications there?

Comment: @GlennFerrie I guess I could try and deploy now to see, but I wanted more of a finished product before I did that. 

I have looked through SendGrid's information from the Azure website and haven't really found anything. I will look a little more. Thanks for the suggestions!

Comment: @RobertPrine - I have had better luck using the .NET types, SmtpClient and MailMessage, when integrating with SendGrid.  You would use the sendgrid smtp host and your sendgrid credentials, and make sure you use port 587.  Here is more info: https://sendgrid.com/docs/Integrate/index.html

Comment: Your ISP or a local firewall may be blocking the outbound traffic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems you can use dotNet `MailMessage` and `SmtpClient` configured using `<system.net> <mailSettings> <smpt>` in web.config file like so.

Sending:

```
    var mailMessage = new MailMessage(...);
    var smtpClient = new SmtpClient();
    smtpClient.Send(message);
```

Configuration for SendGrid in your .config:

```
<system.net>
    <mailSettings>
        <smtp deliveryMethod="Network" from="MYFROM@example.com">
            <network host="smtp.sendgrid.net" password="PASS`"
                     userName="YOURNAME_AZURE_SENDGRID_USERNAME@azure.com" port="587" />
        </smtp>
    </mailSettings>
</system.net>
```

Comment: Thank you @Artyom for your suggested answer! I am relatively new to Visual Studio MVC and am having trouble finding where to put your suggested changes. I'm assuming I would add the .config information instead of my <appSettings> in the web.config, but I'm having trouble with where to put your "Sending" section. I'm assuming it would replace most of IdentityConfig.cs, but I am getting a lot of build errors when I try to switch things around. If you could include any additional specifics about how to combine my current code with yours, I would really appreciate it. Thanks again!

Comment: Yes, [`<system.net>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6484zdc1(v=vs.110).aspx) is to be put into web.config under `<configuration>`. The "Sending" code, the [SmtpClient](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.smtpclient(v=vs.110).aspx) (see the [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.smtpclient(v=vs.110).aspx) for more examples) would go into your `UserManager.SendEmailAsync` method. Hope it helps! Please don't forget to vote the answer.